# How to Moq the "Expression<Func<T, TType>>"

Tags: linq, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, repository-pattern

I am trying to test a Get method of a repository. The signature is as follows:

```
public virtual async Task<IList<TType>> GetAsync<TType>(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter,
            Expression<Func<T, TType>> select = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
......................
}
```

This method is usually invoked in the following manner:

```
var user = await repository.GetAsync(x => x.Name == name, x => new { x.Dob, x.Age });
```

It works fine with real data, When I try to setup this method to return a specific 'User' with a specific lambda where the problems begin.

My question is how to mock the below selector and specify the Returns statement.

```
Expression<Func<T, TType>> select = null,
```

I have tried the below and end up with error.

```
 unitOfWork.Setup(_ => _.repository.GetAsync(
                It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>(),
                It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, object>>>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(users));
```

Error:
cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IList>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IList>'

Can anyone help me, or at least push me in the right direction?

Comment: You can't mock an expression. Like the name already says, it's an expression. It will be read by the repository and so you have to mock the repository `.GetAsync()` and ensure that it can handle the desired *productive expression* and returning the faked results within the test.

Comment: HI Oliver, Thanks for the reply. yes, my question is with in the .GetAsync() how to mock the Expressions.

Comment: Have you tried `.ReturnsAsync(users)`?

Answer (score 0):

[Seems to work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NhWLG0) as expected:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Moq;
using Shouldly;

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyRepository<T>
{
    Task<IList<TType>> GetAsync<TType>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, Expression<Func<T, TType>> select = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);
}

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var users = new List<int>{42};
        var repository = new Mock<IMyRepository<User>>();
        repository.Setup(r => r.GetAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, int>>>(), It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<User>, IOrderedQueryable<User>>>())).ReturnsAsync(users);
        var result = await repository.Object.GetAsync(user => true, user => user.Id, query => query.OrderBy(u => u.Id));
        result.ShouldBe(users);
    }
}
```

The result type depends on your select parameter. If you change its return type, you change the outcome:

```
var users = new List<User> { new User { Id = 42 } };
var repository = new Mock<IMyRepository<User>>();
repository.Setup(r => r.GetAsync(
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>(),
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, User>>>(), // Here you define the outcoming type
    It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<User>, IOrderedQueryable<User>>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(users);

var result = await repository.Object.GetAsync(
    user => true,
    user => user, // Here you define the outcoming type
    query => query.OrderBy(u => u.Id));

result.ShouldBe(users);
```

Comment: HI Oliver, thanks for the reply, one more question, instead of int how to pass a POCO class as return type (EX: user mode with name and id).

Comment: HI Oliver, Thanks for the quick reply, yes its working fine, But in one scenario instead of getting the whole POCO class when i get only required column the mock returns null Value. EX: var result = await repository.Object.GetAsync(
    user => true,
    user => x => new { user.Name }, 
    query => query.OrderBy(u => u.Id));  How to mock this user => x => new { user.Name }. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Mock.Setup method has to return the desired kind of list. The expression itself will be ignored. Check my first example or the fiddle for this kind of result.